# Substraction of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I am trying to subtract 2 dataframes but I am not getting what I want and afterward, I would like to divide the difference by the values of a third dataframe.

For the first part, I have tried to do:

```py
r.sub(rf, fill_value=0)
```

And to be sure that they have the same number of rows, I decided not to drop the na for the moment and I made sure they have the same index name.

Here it is what I have...

[image]

For example, on 2020-01-09, I am supposed to have 0.030079 (=0.136245 - 0.106166).
It looks like it is concatenating the columns of the two dataframes...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not `(first - second) / third` directly?

Comment: Why don't you convert it into numpy arrays and subtract. Ex `sub = np.array(df[key1].to_list()) - np.array(df[key2].to_list())`

Comment: What difference does it make if you convert to numpy arrays or not?

Comment: I did try to do (first - second) / third but I got NaN... I tried also (first - second.values) but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Note that according to your image:

- you have **only one** DataFrame (say *df*) with **two columns**,
- you write about **subtraction** of them, but the second value is
  **negative**.

So run:

```
df['Brent Oil'] + df['S&P GSCI']
```

and e.g. for *2020-01-09* the result will be just *0.030079*.

## Edit

Or maybe you have 2 DataFrames:

- *r* with (the only) *Brent Oil* column,
- *rf* with (also the only) *S&P GSCI* column (with respective positive values),
- and your picture contains the **result** of subtraction?

If this is the case, subtract the given columns, not whole DataFrames:

```
r['Brent Oil'].sub(rf['S&P GSCI'], fill_value=0)
```

Then the result will be a *Series*, with value just *0.030079* for
*2020-01-09*.

You could also run `np.array(r['Brent Oil']) - np.array(rf['S&P GSCI'])`
(something similar to what *Anurag Reddy* proposed), but then you get
only a *Numpy* array, with index stripped off, so it is not obvious
which difference is for which date and it is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have 2 DataFrames. And actually, 3...

I have a loop and r is supposed to be a temporary data frame, in which I store:

- a specific date index (e.g. Date.0, Date.1...)
- a specific asset (e.g. Brent Oil, Crude Oil...)

from a third DataFrame 
[(this one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiDDB.png) which combines all the data together.

Then for each asset, I wanted to subtract rf [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjZqT.png)

I made sure to have the same starting and ending dates, with:

```
    start=r.index[0]
    end=r.index.dropna()[-1]
```

But yes at the end, I am trying to get again a dataframe.

I will try your suggestion with a dynamic variable for the name!

```
r['Brent Oil'].sub(rf['S&P GSCI'], fill_value=0)
```